# Cronjob Not Running On Local Timezone

Tags: php, cron, ini

I have set date.timezone="Asia/Kolkata" in php.ini files in Home directory and Public_html directory.

Also tried to edit .htaccess files as follows :

```
#Adjust default time zone 
#SetEnv TZ Asia/Kolkata
```

phpinfo() is also showing date.timezone="Asia/Kolkata"

But till cronjob running on UTC and not on my local Asia/Kolkata timezone.

I contacted hosting providers, they said please edit script and your php.ini files. I reviewed my scripts and php.ini files many times...Till NO SUCCESS.

few first lines in my php.ini file is home directory is as follow :

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata"
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;
; WARNING ;
;;;;;;;;;;;
; This is the default settings file for new PHP installations.
; By default, PHP installs itself with a configuration suitable for
; development purposes, and *NOT* for production purposes.
; For several security-oriented considerations that should be taken
; before going online with your site, please consult php.ini-recommended
; and http://php.net/manual/en/security.php.
.
 .
  .
```

php info can be seen here

http://ayurvedvishva.com/phpinfo

I am on shared hosting, so no access to SSH / WHM

Comment: Cronjob would be running as per the system timing (server)

Answer (score 1):

Cronjob runs on the server time schedule, and has nothing to do with PHP. For a quick glance at what timezone your server is running in, type `date +%Z;` in a shell.

Edit: Without access to SSH, and on shared hosting you should adjust your cron time for the server time provided to you. This is a limitation of shared hosting. Setting the TZ environment variable will only start processes with the timezone, but your cron will still run on the servers schedule

Comment: In phpinfo() file, At bottom, I have added echo current date time.... it is showing Asia/Kolkata date timing.... e.g. it is showing right now 2015-09-15 10:39:13 which is my current date and time in my area...you can see it at bottom on link http://ayurvedvishva.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: When PHP executes, you are setting the timezone of the PHP process itself (via ini or code). Outside of PHP there is a time associated with the operating system, and that is what the crontab is scheduled against.